# Node.js OpenAI trouble establishing a simple connection

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I have a short simple file that was written and taken directly from the openai-node GitHub repository:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_KEY,
})

async function main() {
    const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        messages: [{role: 'user', content: 'Say this is a test'}],
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    });
}

main();
```

I have a successful connection, but I'm guessing it keeps hitting the API nonstop, because I get the following error:

```
            return new RateLimitError(status, error, message, headers);
                   ^

RateLimitError: 429 You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.
    at APIError.generate (file:///home/matt/web/website1/node_modules/openai/error.mjs:57:20)
    at OpenAI.makeStatusError (file:///home/matt/web/website1/node_modules/openai/core.mjs:244:25)
    at OpenAI.makeRequest (file:///home/matt/web/website1/node_modules/openai/core.mjs:283:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async main (file:///home/matt/web/website1/index.js:12:18) {
  status: 429,
```

The TPM limit for the gpt-3.5-turbo model is 40,000 and I'm pretty sure that this code isn't hitting that limit so I'm confused why I'm getting the error.

I am using a free trial on OpenAI maybe that's why I can't get a successful response. All I want to do is have access to ChatGPT from my web application.